# path name lookup in Linux?

Tags: linux, history

Linus Torvalds mentioned in a talk that path name lookup in Linux is the fastest of all OSes, and that can happen in 1000-core machines without any slow downs. He mentioned this work happened in the last 18 months, but I can't find any references to the details of this development. Are there any documents explaining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out your `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems` for the file `path-lookup.txt` or go to http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/path-lookup.txt - it explains it in detail.

Comment: The article mentioned at the end of the document is pretty cool. Thanks! http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7124

Comment: More links  https://lwn.net/Articles/419811/ and http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_38#head-bd31172f390514636ace788ff8287aa620e5ea3f